# Unable to get payment method from Observer class

Tags: magento2, module

I'm unable to get the payment method from the sales_order_save_after observer class in a custom module, i can get the orderId and Name but i have been unable to work out how to get the payment method (paypal, bank transfer etc)

My observer class:

```
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface { 

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $orderId = $order->getId();
      $customerName = "";

      //$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
      //$paymentmethod = $payment->getMethod();

      if ($order->getCustomerFirstname()) {
        $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
      } else {
       // guest customer
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $customerName = $billingAddress->getFirstname() . ' ' . 
        $billingAddress->getLastname();
      }

      $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/debug.log');
      $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();

      $logger->addWriter($writer);
      $logger->info('User has placed a new order. Order ID: ' . $orderId . '. Name: ' . $customerName . ". Payment Method: " . $paymentMethod);
 }

}
```

***The $paymentmethod commented out throws an error :***

```
 "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethod()
 on null in
```

Comment: `$paymentmethod = $order->getPayment()->getMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

It should work with

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethod();
```

Comment: Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethod() on null in